# contentful documentHtmlToString format links

Tags: javascript, contentful

I am using contentful for our CMS needs and using the contentful SDK for JavaScript.
I am trying to use their **documentToHtmlString** method to add some attributes to my anchor links.
I have tried doing it like this:

```
return documentToHtmlString(text, {
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, next) => {
      let content: any[] = [];

      node.content.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.nodeType === 'hyperlink') {
          let itemContent = item.content[0];
          let value = itemContent['value'];

          let uri = item.data.uri;
          console.log(value, uri);

          content.push(
            `<p><a href="${uri}" data-category="contact" data-action="email">${value}</a></p>`
          );
        } else {
          content.push(`<p>${next([item])}</p>`);
        }
      });

      console.log(content.join(''));

      return content.join('');
    },
  },
});
```

But when I inspect the result, it doesn't have my **data-category** or **data-action**.
Is there a better way to add attributes to a link?

Their documentation shows this:
https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/rendering-contentful-rich-text-with-javascript/

but there is no mention of anchors :(

---

The plot thickens...
I figured maybe it doesn't like data attributes, so I added a few more:

```
content.push(
  `<p><a class="test" href="${uri}" category="contact" data-category="contact" data-action="email" target="_blank">${value}</a></p>`
);
```

and what actually gets rendered is this:

```
<a class="test" href="mailto:bob@example.com" target="_blank">bob@example.com</a>
```

Notice how it's added **class** and **target**, but omitted **category**, **data-category** and **data-action**.....

---

Thanks to @stefan-judis for telling me about inline.
I have now updated my code to this:

```
[INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, next) => {
  console.log(node);

  let value = node.content[0]['value'];
  let uri = node.data.uri;

  return `<a class="test" href="${uri}" data="test" category="contact" data-category="contact" data-action="email" target="_blank">${value}</a>`;
},
```

and I removed the **BLOCKS** code, but unfortunately, I still get the same issue. It is not rendering all the attributes (only **class** and **target**). Infact, it renders exactly the same as above. It's like there is some internal formatting that removes attributes...

Comment: Heyo, Contentful DevRel here. I just recently recorded an episode that covers more or less your case. Maybe it's helpful. :) https://www.contentful.com/developers/videos/learn-graphql/#rendering-of-contentful-richtext

Comment: Thanks, I watched your video which was easy to follow, but unfortunately, it didn't work. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stefan was correct with his answer; it was Angular that was messing up my content.
I had to use angulars `DomSanitizer` to fix the problem like this:

```
public htmlToString(text: any): SafeHtml {
  const renderOptions = {
    renderNode: {
      [INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, next) => {
        return `<a href="${node.data.uri}" style="background: red; color: white;" data-foo>${next(node.content)}</a>`;
      },
    },
  };

  const content = documentToHtmlString(text, renderOptions);

  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
}
```

That allowed me to add it to my html like this:

```
<div class="content" [innerHtml]="section.content"></div>
```

And it all worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

I created [a quick example achieving your desired outcome](https://codesandbox.io/s/richtext-render-example-x1q4h?file=/src/index.js:327-1017).

```
client.getEntry("...").then(({ fields }) => {
  const richText = fields.richText;

  const renderOptions = {
    renderNode: {
      // this is the important part 
      [INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, next) => {
        console.log(node);
        return `<a href="${
          node.data.uri
        }" style="background: red; color: white;" data-foo>${next(
          node.content
        )}</a>`;
      },
      [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: (node, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  };
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = documentToHtmlString(
    richText,
    renderOptions
  );
});
```

I'm not sure what going on in your environment, but as you see on CodeSandbox, the code renders data attributes and everything. :)

Comment: It's strange; I copied your answer and pasted it into my code. If I put a console log like this:  `console.log(this.contentfulService.htmlToString(this.component.fields.content));` I can actually see that it has all the properties. But it never gets rendered like that. I should point out I am using angular and I don't do `document.getElementById` but instead I do this: `<div class="content" [innerHtml]="section.content"></div>`

Comment: Then it seems to be an Angular thing and unfortunately, I can't help with that. :/

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out. I will post here!